# Error when trying to launch moveit created robot model

Tags: rviz, moveit, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a simulated robot in Gazebo that can be operated with use of the Moveit. I created a robot using moveit assistant, placed it in catkin workspace folder and built it. But when I try to launch it, i get an error, that says:

```
You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1506611133.048666841]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1506611133.048829426]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::Exception'
what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(5:): Could not find font Liberation Sans in MovableText::setFontName
```

I checked for the liberation sans font with synaptic, even reinstalled it, but the error remains.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271750/error-when-trying-to-launch-moveit-created-robot-model/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-28**:
Note btw that this is most likely not a problem with your MoveIt configuration, but with RViz. You could verify that by running just RViz (using something like `rosrun rviz rviz` or just `rviz`).

**Comment by [Fiddle](https://answers.ros.org/users/32064/fiddle/) on 2017-09-28**:
the rviz runs normally when i try that

**Comment by [ddomit](https://answers.ros.org/users/32091/ddomit/) on 2017-10-07**:
You have to add it (paste it) interested RVIZ font directory NOT the one of your Linux system, the RVIZ directory directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This shouldn't be required, the real solution is for moveit to make sure they have the fonts they use, or ensure that they are using the same font as rviz. I would look to a resolution to https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/624 for a permanent solution.

EDIT: update is that this is caused by a configuration issue with when building from source. Make sure that if you're building rviz from source that you have the latest sources and that you've rebuilt your workspace (delete the build, devel, and install folders and build it again) as well as having your deb packages up-to-date (`sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rviz` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1